# UITableView with data from array

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4, nsarray

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in it. I now want do fill up this table view with my data from array. But the problem is that it doesn't show anything.

This is my implementation file:

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@implementation MenuViewController
@synthesize menuArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.menuArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Catalogus",@"Wishlist", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.menuArray = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.menuArray count];
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

This is my header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *menuArray;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *menuArray;

@end
```

And in my Xib file I have both the data source and delegate connected to files owner.

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: Is it the whole header file? If so, you may need to make an 'IBOutlet UITableView *yourTableview;' and connect it in the xib

Answer (score 1):

Set Delegate and DataSource for your tableView.
 it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Where you set up your array, reload the table...

```
self.menuArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Catalogus",@"Wishlist", nil];
[myTable reloadData];
```

Change 'myTable' to the name of your table, which you will need to add to the header as a variable and connect via IB if you are using it.

Comment: I used the same code what @user1155884 has provided. In the nib I had a tableview set to files owner datasource and delegate. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console if you have any errors and let us know.